# I can't show the Deployment Settings in BIDS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, bids

I have an analysis services database which contains datasources, data source views, dimensions and cubes. I want to edit the Project Properties for it by right-clicking the highest level, then clicking properties, but I don't get anything: it doesn't show the properties. If I create a new empty project I can get the properties page without difficulty.

Is it possible that this is blocked for security reasons? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have used the BIDS menu command File / Open / Analysis Services Database. In that case you are directly editing the schema.  Clicking Save will "deploy" your changes.

Comment: There are no Project Properties in this scenario.